# How to get distinct node sets?

Tags: xml, nodes, xslt-2.0

How can I retrieve distinct node sets from a document?
I have played around with the `distinct-values` function, but it did not give me the desired result. See this example:

This stylesheet,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="distinct">
        <foo>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <a>3</a>
            <b>4</b>
        </foo>
    </xsl:variable>

    <result>
        <xsl:copy-of select="distinct-values($distinct/foo)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

applied on any document gives me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">12 34</result>
```

Apparently it recongises that node sets `foo[1]` and `foo[2]` are identical, but it only ouptuts the vales of each node, not the node sets themselves.

I would like an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:aux="http://dummy">
    <foo>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>2</b>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <a>3</a>
        <b>4</b>
     </foo>
</result>
```

The duplicate nodes can be spread throughout the document in any order.

A small update to the question: What can I do if I only have to check uniqueness of child nodes a and not b (like in my example, in the first two foo nodes, values of bare different, I still only want one nodeset for these in the output)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `deep-equal` you can use: `<xsl:copy-of select="$distinct/foo[every $foo in following::foo satisfies not(deep-equal(., $foo))]"/>`. Or maybe the other way around: `<xsl:copy-of select="$distinct/foo[every $foo in preceding::foo satisfies not(deep-equal(., $foo))]"/>`.

Comment: Thanks, deep-equal was unknown to me before.

Comment: A small update to the question: What can I do if I only have to check uniqueness of child nodes `a` and not `b` (like in my example, in the first two `foo` nodes, values of `b`are different, I still only want one nodeset for these in the output)? Thanks

Comment: In the case I suggest to use `<xsl:for-each-group select="$distinct/fpo" group-by="a"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:for-each-group>`. (`<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` inside the `for-each-group` is equivalent to `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>` as the context node `.` is the first item in each group).

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming here you are doing server-side JS with NodeJS (based on tags in question)?*

Try checking NPM modules for suitable XML package that can either parse the XML for you, or perhaps translate to JavaScript.

[xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) is one module that looks like it might help. I will do a little research and update this answer, but putting this here as a placeholder, and giving you a chance to also check NPM for modules that might help.

Here is some working code:

foo.xml (modified as proof of concept):

```
<start>
  <foo>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <a>3</a>
    <b>4</b>
  </foo>
</start>
```

app.js:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  xml2js = require('xml2js'),
  _ = require('lodash');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
  parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
    var res = _.uniq(result.start.foo, function (n) {
      return JSON.toString(n);
    });
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have no knwoledge in JavaScript and I do not use node.js. This tag has been edited by someone else, I have removed it now.

Comment: @WilliFischer - which language are you coding in?

Comment: @WilliFischer - no worries, the fact you used "Node" in your title likely confused someone with the tagging process.  Shame, since the solution I provided would have worked well ;)

Comment: Thanks anyway, maybe this is useful to someone elase some time